# Removing time from my Date variable

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have my Date of Birth variable which is initially of type int. It is then parsed toString() and parsed to Date with simpleDateFormat.

The only issue is that it keeps returning it's default time including the date.

```
public Date getDob(){
    String format = Integer.toString(this.dob);
    try{
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(format);
    }catch(ParseException e){
        return null;
    }
    return date;
}
```

Returns: Sat Jan 16 **00:00:00 CET 1999** [ I want to remove the bold time ]

Thank you very much for your help!

Solution:

```
public String getDob(){
    Date newDate = new Date(this.dob);
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd").format(newDate);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `format`?

Comment: Once the dob variable is parsed, String format = "16011999"
16th January 1999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A java.util.Date object by definition has both a date portion and a time-of-day portion.

## Date-Time != String

Understand that a date-time object is *not* a String. We create String representations of the date-time value contained within a date-time object, but doing so is generating a fresh String object completely separate from the date-time object.

## LocalDate

If you want only a date, without the notion of time-of-day, use the LocalDate class found in both [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

## Joda-Time

By default, Joda-Time uses the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats. If you want Strings in other formats, explore the [DateTimeFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) class (a factory of DateTimeFormatters).

Example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
String input = "01021903"; // First of February, 1903.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "ddMMyyyy" );
LocalDate dateOfBirth = formatter.parseLocalDate( input );
String outputStandard = dateOfBirth.toString();  // By default, the ISO 8601 format is used.
String outputCustom = formatter.print( dateOfBirth );
```

Comment: Thanks Basil, sorry for the late reply. Going to try this and answer back!

Comment: I'd like to say a big thanks Basil, I was told to use Joda-Time but it did confuse me quite a bit. Your example really helped and got it working perfectly! Have a good day

Comment: @Booch Yes, there is a bit of a learning curve on Joda-Time. **Well worth the effort** if you do any date-time work. [Search StackOverflow for "joda"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=joda) to find many example to quickly flatten that curve.

Comment: Thanks once again Basil :-)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change `toString()` method of `Date` class,

what you are doing is you are parsing some String to Date and returning Date instance and trying to print it which internally invokes `toString()` of `Date` and it has fixed format,

You can use `format()` method to convert `Date` to `String` and print it in whatever format you want

Comment: Better solution: use Joda Time or java.time, both of which have a type representing "just a date"

Comment: So how should I go about this? To give you the idea of the situation, I'm basically designing a very basic database. The student constructor contains int dob parameter, that parameter is parsed into string which is then formatted in date variable of type Data.

Comment: just parse input to Date and where you want to display it in pretty format, use SimpleDateformat#format()

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, editing the original post right now :-) thanks everyone

Comment: This is what my comment above tells :)

Comment: Thanks again Jigar, I understood it now! All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Date originalDate = new Date();
long timeInMills = originalDate.getTime();

Date newDate = new Date(timeInMills);
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd").format(newDate);

System.out.println(date);
```

output:

```
Wed Apr 30
```

If you want to store the date in long (in milliseconds) if needed.

For more pattern have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Im not entirely sure if this works. Basically dob refers to Date of Birth which is used in my Object's constructor, from what I'm reading this give current date?

Comment: Alright will try this out! Back with you in a moment :)

Comment: It was working very well! However the format that I can output with Joda-Time seems much neater. E.g 1996/09/02 which is exactly how I wanted it to be! Your code works very well too :)

Comment: @Booch no worries just asking.