# How to convert String into Date in this format yyyy-MM-dd ?

Tags: java

I am working on dateFormat in java,I am facing some problem,Please check my code below

```
String sDate = "2014-05-20";
Date convertDate = new Date(s);
System.out.println(convertDate );
```

It's working fine but the output is like

```
OutPut:Tue May 20 13:52:40 IST 2014
```

but I dont' won't the output like this ,I want out put same as String format

```
ExpectedOutput :2014-05-20
```

how can i do this any one help me

Comment: Why not use [LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class of Java 8? You're getting the output you're getting because the `toString()` method of `Date` class returns the kind of `String` that is getting displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394809/removing-time-from-my-date-variable/23394829#23394829

Comment: Try researching first before posting

Answer (score 4):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(yyy-MM-dd);
Date yourNewDate = sdf.parse(sDate);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe (+1)

Comment: I done that..but I don't want in String Object...I want in Date Object  with same format

Comment: a date object dosen't have a format.... only when its converted to a string will it have a format..

mind you this example is syntactically incorrect anyway

Comment: SimpleDateFormat parse() will return  Date not String.

Comment: Check my code again :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        SimpleDateFormat d=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d1=d.parse("2014-05-20");
        System.out.println(d.format(d1));
```

[working example](http://ideone.com/PoynCv)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to set the Format of the Date. Do like below:

```
String sDate = "2014-05-20";

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date convertDate =dateFormat.parse(sDate);
System.out.println(convertDate );
```

Comment: I dont wont this format :Tue May 20 00:00:00 IST 2014 I want again this format 2014-05-20 but in Date object